# containers in the same network unable to communicate

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have a Docker bridge network, to which are attached 2 containers:

- a Node.js server running on the port 3333
- a Flask server running on the port 5000

The network has this configuration:

```js
[
    {
        "Name": "mynetwork",
        "Id": "f94f76533b065d39515b65d20b8645c22617be51ec9335fcfad8ce707ca48841",
        "Created": "2019-02-20T17:17:29.029434324+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.1.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "10.1.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "Containers": {
            "c8084141e36c756710cbfa020f664127f234e407986362331ab127d415c9b074": {
                "Name": "nodeContainer",
                "EndpointID": "e25f8797c1b7488d7c3810d8f38c4b3dea6b9f19f17558a164b710015fdd9e1a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:01:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.1.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f9c582d031515f4bba910286118df806a6a2b04a36917234eca09fdf335d4457": {
                "Name": "flaskContainer",
                "EndpointID": "fbf053f97acc7b9491c536966b640862d366d1599fbfb400915cd8bc26b04f6a",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:01:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "10.1.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Normally, those 2 containers communicate (`nodeContainer` makes requests to `http://flaskContainer:5000`), but this stopped to work after setting a different `Subnet` and `Gateway` (for external network constraints).

In particular, I get an error like `ETIMEDOUT 10.1.0.2:3333`. This makes me think that the address is correctly resolved, but for some reason, there is no answer (and in fact `flaskContainer` logs nothing).

As additional information:

```
docker exec flaskContainer curl flaskContainer
docker exec nodeContainer curl nodeContainer
```

obviously does not work (`Failed to connect to flaskContainer port 80`).

```
docker exec flaskContainer curl flaskContainer:5000
docker exec nodeContainer curl nodeContainer:3333
```

correctly give results.

```
docker exec flaskContainer curl nodeContainer:3333
docker exec nodeContainer curl flaskContainer:5000
```

goes in timeout.

Have you any idea of what can be the reason? How can I solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but shouldn't ```"Subnet": "10.1.0.1/16"``` really be ```"Subnet": "10.1.0.0/16"```.

Comment: @SteveBoyd it seems to be unrelated

Comment: What does the route table in your host look like? `ip r`

Comment: default via 192.168.104.1 dev eno1 onlink 
| 10.0.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 
| 10.1.0.0/16 dev br-2db6554fc133 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.0.1 linkdown 
| 172.18.0.0/16 dev br-088bbcb085bb proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 
| 192.168.104.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.104.204 
@BMitch